# Change of variables - Wirtinger derivatives

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, proof-explanation

This is from my class. How did the lecturer get the last two equalities?

[image]

[image]

Comment: look like **definitions** to me.

Comment: Yes but they don't follow from the previous part?

Answer (score 2):

It is just the multi-variable chain rule. You have
$$(x(z,\bar{z}),y(z,\bar{z})) := (\frac{z+\bar{z}}{2},\frac{z-\bar{z}}{2i}) $$
so
$$\frac{\partial }{\partial z} f(x(z,\bar{z}),y(z,\bar{z})) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dz} +  \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dz} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{1}{2} +  \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{-i}{2}$$
and similarily for $\frac{\partial}{\partial\bar{z}}f$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you elaborate on the equality$\frac{\partial}{\partial z} f(x(z, \bar{z}), y(z, \bar{z}))=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{d x}{d z}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{d y}{d z}$? I'm relearning many calculus stuffs from ages ago, so I'd like to know the details.

Answer (score 1):

In the expression $df = \cfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx+\cfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy$, just substitute for $dx$ and $dy$. As you've put it, $dx = \cfrac{dz+d\bar{z}}{2}$ and $dy = \cfrac{dz-d\bar{z}}{2i}$. So, $df$ becomes:

$$df= \cfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}\bigg{(}\cfrac{dz+d\bar{z}}{2}\bigg{)}+\cfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}\bigg{(}\cfrac{dz-d\bar{z}}{2i}\bigg{)}$$

Regroup like terms and arrive at:

$$df= \cfrac{1}{2}\bigg{(}\cfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\cfrac{\partial f}{i\partial y}\bigg{)}dz+\cfrac{1}{2}\bigg{(}\cfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}-\cfrac{\partial f}{i\partial y}\bigg{)}d\bar{z}$$

Note: $\cfrac{1}{i}=-i$

Also, $df$ is defined as $df = \cfrac{\partial f}{\partial z}dz+\cfrac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}}d\bar{z}$. This follows from the total differential for $f(z,\bar{z})$. Additionally, note that the so called Cauchy Riemman (CR) conditions really equal $\cfrac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}}=0$. This is a "one-step" method to check whether a function $f(z,\bar{z})$ does satisfy the CR conditions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you elaborate a bit more on the total differential (like when it's ok to use that form)? I'm relearning many calculus stuffs from ages ago, so I'd like to know the details.